# How do I compile SASL support into Postfix-3.0.0 on OS X 10.10.3

Tags: c++, macos, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to compile Postfix-3.0.0 with SASL support from sources from postfix.org, and run into a little snag.
The build is looking for

```
dict_ni.c:39:10: fatal error: 'netinfo/ni.h' file not found
#include <netinfo/ni.h>
```

But I can't figure out what to put in the make makefiles line....
This works for TLS

```
make makefiles CCARGS="-DUSE_TLS -I/usr/local/include"  AUXLIBS="-L/opt/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto”
```

So any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I found the answer, thanks to Viktor, of Postfix.org. 
 # Dovecot only with Dovecot as default
   #
   make -f Makefile.init dynamicmaps=yes CCARGS='-DUSE_TLS -DHAS_PCRE -DUSE_SASL_AUTH -DDEF_SERVER_SASL_TYPE=\"dovecot\" -I/opt/local/include' AUXLIBS='-L/opt/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto' AUXLIBS_PCRE='-L/opt/local/lib -lpcre' makefiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out. This works on Yosemite 10.10.3, with Postfix-3.1, Dovecot installed, and Mysql, and SASL&TLS compiled in.
I used new - the latest at time of writing, postfix-3.1.xxx, and the latest Dovecot.

```
make -f Makefile.init dynamicmaps=yes CCARGS='-DHAS_MYSQL -I/usr/local/include/mysql -DUSE_TLS -DUSE_SASL_AUTH -DDEF_SERVER_SASL_TYPE=\"dovecot\" -DHAS_PCRE -I/opt/local/include' 'AUXLIBS=-L/opt/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto' 'AUXLIBS_MYSQL=-L/usr/local/lib -lmysqlclient -lz -lm' 'AUXLIBS_PCRE=-L/opt/local/lib -lpcre’ makefiles
```

FYI.